# Pillow лупа на изображение

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow

Как реализовать функцию лупа, то есть приближать и отдалать изобаржение.
Я использую pyllow и tkinter для отображения изображения

```
img = Image.open('image.jpeg')
filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
background = Label(window, image=filename)
background.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: Как работать должно? При наведении мыши на изображение где-то в отдельном окне должно отображаться увеличенное изображение?

Comment: @insolor Я по началу согласен на любой вариант, и просто прокрутка колесиком с изменной исходного вывода изображения и по нажтию кнопок. И вариант с наведением мыши с выводом небольшого отдельного окна или наложением на исходное некой увеличиной облости. главное чтобы можно было и приблизить, и отдалить, если использольвотать просто зумирование.